# What do the orbits look like on a torus given as $C\times C$ acted upon by $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to better understand how the following group action looks like on a torus. The group $\mathbb{R}$ acts on the torus $C\times C=\{(e^{ix},e^{iy}):x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ ($C$ being the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$) via $$t\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})\mapsto (e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy})$$

I am able (I think) to visualize the torus based on the definition of $C\times C$: the first coordinate gives us the ring of unit length in the donut and, as $x$ sweeps through $\mathbb{R}$, the second coordinate gives us the "hollow body" of the donut, again of unit length, as $y$ sweeps through $\mathbb{R}$. So here is where the problems begin for me.

1. What am I doing wrong to show that this a homomorphism? $$st\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})\mapsto (e^{i(x+st)},e^{iy})$$ but $$[s\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})][t\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})] = (e^{i(x+s)},e^{iy})(e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy}) = (e^{i(2x+s+t)},e^{i2y})$$
2. For $t\in \mathbb{R}$, the orbit $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is $\{(e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy}):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Is this any different from $C\times C$?

Comment: It's not a homomorphism. For non-integer $t$, this maps zero to a non-zero element. (It is a *homeomorphism* though, of $C\times C$)

Comment: Strange, my book assumes it is. Here is the text verbatim "The real number $t$ sends $(e^{ix},e^{iy})$ to $(e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy})$." Maybe I didn't represent this properly?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just meant to check that it's a group action? So you need to show that $st.x = s.(t.x)$ for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}, x\in C\times C$.

Comment: Yes. A group action of $G$ on $X$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_X$ No?

Comment: Well that's not what you were checking :). Write out the definition carefully for a group homomorphism from $G$ to $S_X$.

Comment: Am I looking at $\mathbb{R}$ as an additive group?

Comment: Multipilcation doesn't give a well defined group structure on $\mathbb{R}$, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

It will be a whole lot easier to study this action by representing the torus as $\mathbf R^2/\mathbf Z^2$. Then your action comes from the action of $\mathbf R$ on $\mathbf R^2$ defined by
$$
t\cdot(x,y)=(x+\tfrac1{2\pi} t,y).
$$
It is clear that this is an action, it is just the action by translation on the right of the additive subgroup $\mathbf R=\mathbf R\times\{0\}$ of $\mathbf R^2$. The orbits are the affine lines parallel to the $x$-axis. In the torus this correpsonds to the circles $C\times\{*\}$, where $*$ is any point of the second factor $C$.

Comment: The representation of the torus you give, what sort of space does it live in? I can't visualize it.

Comment: @JacopoStifani we can make a torus by identifying opposite sides of a cube. The answer choose to "identify" by taking one $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ (as say, the identification on the $x$ axis), and then the other $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ as identification on the $y$ axis.

$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ acts as identification since it causes the number line to "wrap around" every $1$ distance

Comment: @Jacopo Stifani It does not live in any ambient space in a natural way. It is the quotient of the additive group $\mathbf R^2$ by the subgroup $\mathbf Z^2$. I figured you knew what a quotient group is, otherwise never mind!

Comment: @Dan Rust Well, $2\pi$ acts trivially on $C\times C$, so I wanted it to act trivially on $\mathbf R^2/\mathbf Z^2$ as well. Otherwise the $\mathbf R$-sets $C\times C$ and $\mathbf R^2/\mathbf Z^2$ would not be isomorphic as $\mathbf R$-sets.

Comment: I have an introductory knowledge of quotient groups but when I sketch an element of $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it looks like a bunch of equally spaced out points, not a torus.

Comment: Yeah, but if you choose a representative for every coset $(x,y)+\mathbf Z^2$ you tend to end up with $[0,1)\times[0,1)$. Taking the topology into account,  if a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ in that half-open square tends to a point $(1,y)$ in $\{1\}\times[0,1)$, for example, then its limit in the quotient is really the point $(0,y)$! That's how you see that it is a torus.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to 1.

Thanks to @Dan Rust, I see the mistake in (1). Firstly, let it be clear that the group operation on $\mathbb{R}$ is addition (multiplication cannot give it such structure). Secondly, this line $$[s\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})][t\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})] = (e^{i(x+s)},e^{iy})(e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy}) = (e^{i(2x+s+t)},e^{i2y})$$ is incorrect: instead of showing composition of permutations I mixed in multiplication of coordinates. It should be $$(s+t)\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})\mapsto (e^{i(x+s+t)},e^{iy})$$ and $$s\cdot[t\cdot (e^{ix},e^{iy})] = s\cdot (e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy}) = (e^{i(x+t+s)},e^{iy})$$ which are indeed equal.

Answer to 2.

Thanks to @Johannes Huisman, I see my mistake and use his description of the orbits. The orbits should be written as $$\mathbb{R}(e^{ix},e^{iy}) = \{(e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy}):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$$and not $\mathbb{R}(t) = \{(e^{i(x+t)},e^{iy}):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. So, for a specific point $(e^{ix},e^{iy})$ on the torus, our orbit will be all points of the form $(e^{i(x+t)},*)$ where $*$ is a fixed point on $C$. As $t$ sweeps through $\mathbb{R}$, we end up with a circle parallel to the plane on which the circle $\{e^{ix}\}$ lies.

Comment: Anybody know a good software to generate a dynamic picture of these orbits?